# AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.manifold._barnes_hut_tsne.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to run a code in Python to import Kmeans using sklearn. However, when I try to import, I get this error message:

> AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.manifold._barnes_hut_tsne.array' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

sklearn is installed with all the necessary packages. I'm unsure as to what the problem might be. Here is part of the code from my work involving the import:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
num_clusters = 8
km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
%time km.fit(tfidf_matrix)
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```

even if I put `from sklearn.cluster import KMeans` all by itself, I get the same error, so the error is coming from that line of code alone. Any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE:** I am using Jupyter Notebook and yes, I have installed any and all necessary packages as well as updated sklearn.

Comment: How did you install sklearn & did you build the cython parts? Maybe all cython parts are missing, and this is just the first of many failures?

Comment: I have solved this problem! I had installed sklearn through anaconda. I also have it installed on PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstalled scipy and installed it again and restarted
the kernel and then run the code.
It worked for me.
Basically it is due to the Kernel restart issue.